# How can I avoid code duplication when configuring widgets I build using JavaScript object literals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I know there is probably some very small and simple inheritance or extension solution for this, but I hope this question will prove beneficial for more than just me. And quicker.

I have e.g. the following code to set up a [Kendo UI grid](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/grid/overview.aspx). I need to repeat this code exactly for two grids on the same view, except for one parameter difference in the `transport.read.data` object. I realise I can factor out the `model` and `columns` definitions into shared objects, but I would like to share the whole grid config eventually. Maybe a jQuery extension called `myUserKendoGrid`?

```
    $("#availableUsersGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Role/AvailableUsersJson",
                    data: { roleId: $("#Id").val() },
                    type: "GET"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false },
                        UserName: { editable: false },
                        EmployeeRefNum: { editable: false },
                        EmployeeSurname: { editable: false },
                        EmployeeFullNames: { editable: false }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
                { field: "UserName", title: "User Name" },
                { field: "EmployeeRefNum", title: "Emp. No." },
                { field: "EmployeeSurname", title: "Surname" },
                { field: "EmployeeFullNames", title: "Name" }
        ],
        selectable: "multiple, row",
        editable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply clone your configuration via the `.extend()` method of **jQuery**. For example:

```
var superDuperAwesomeConfiguration = {
    // moar configs go here, yo!
};

var copyCatConfigs = jQuery.extend(true, {}, superDuperAwesomeConfiguration);

// modify copyCatConfigs properties here

$("#gridA").kendoGrid(superDuperAwesomeConfiguration);
$("#gridB").kendoGrid(copyCatConfigs);
```

Comment: Thanks John. My docs for jQuery give me the signature `jQuery.extend([deep], target, object1, [objectN]) : Object` for a deep extend, which is what I assume you intend, based on your first param being `true`. Surely `superDuperAwesomeConfiguration` is the target and thus the second param in that case? Scuse my jQuery/Friday stoopidz.